# Vainfo returns "libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed" in dual gpu system

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a dual gpu system.  It has a 2nd generation Sandy Bridge iGPU and an nvidia 650ti.  The Nvidia gpu is connected to the display and is using the proprietary drivers.  I'm trying to use the iGPU for video encoding.

I have installed the va driver using

```
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver
```

If I run `vainfo` it returns:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

But if I run `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 vainfo` it returns:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'i965'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Comment: I finally made some progress on this.  I don't know why I'm getting the error in the original question.  But if I use 'vainfo --display drm --device /dev/dri/renderD128' it returns that the intel driver is working and that the intel driver is that render device.  If I try it with 'renderD129', which is the Nvidia device, it fails.  I don't mind this, because my goal was to encode using Quicksync in Linux, using OBS.  With the new version 23x of OBS I am able to do this, and have determined that it is the correct device with the command.

Answer (score 9):

A little late, but I ran into the same problem so I thought I'd leave what worked for me. Apparently you need the VDPAU (http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/vdpau/doxygen/html/index.html) wrapper.

```
sudo apt-get install vdpau-va-driver
```

After that it returns fine.

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_0
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems VDPAU backend for VA-API - 0.7.4
```

Comment: Oh, thanks.  vainfo now shows that it's working with the nvidia driver.  `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 vainfo` still returns an error though.  It's possible that using both at the same time isn't possible, or that something else is broken.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install vdpau-va-driver` should not work on recent version of Ubuntu since the package is missing in the sources. So not sure how this answer addresses the original question. Maybe your are using some older version Ubuntu or a different Linux distribution like Debian.

Comment: @StéphaneTréboux Considering that this answer is about 2 years older than your comment, you can expect that it was an earlier version of Ubuntu (or Debian).

Answer (score 8):

The package [`vdpau-va-driver`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/vdpau-va-driver) is required for hardware acceleration with the NVIDIA proprietary drivers. Canonical dropped the package `vdpau-va-driver` some time ago for no clear reason. [This is reported in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libva-utils/+bug/1890815), please feel free to report that you are affected by clicking on "Does this bug affect you?".

Debian provides an up to date version, currently 0.7.4-7, which can be downloaded [here](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vdpau-video) (download the latest 32 bit 64 bit versions) and installed from a command line by running `dpkg -i` on the respective packages. After the installation the command `vainfo` is happy again and returns, among other things:

```
vainfo: Driver version: Splitted-Desktop Systems VDPAU backend for VA-API - 0.7.4
```

[You can then refer to this guide from ArchWiki on how to take advantage of VDPAU in different applications.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration#Configuring_applications)

Comment: When I try to install `vdpau-va-driver` it says `However the following packages replace it:
  mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-va-drivers`. `mesa-va-drivers` is installed but the problem persists

Comment: Hi @raffaem, is it possible that you are using the open source Nouveau driver instead of the proprietary Nvidia driver which is being discussed here? Nouveau is FOSS and distributed as part of Mesa. The proprietary Nvidia driver is closed source and distributed by Nvidia.

Comment: I just checked on my system and mesa-va-drivers is installed alongside vdpau-va-driver and poses no issue. I reinstalled vdpau-va-driver using dpkg and could not see any error message. So you see other error messages?

Comment: No I'm using NVIDIA proprietary I am sure. I avoided the problem by using VDPAU directly in MVP

Comment: I face a regression when using VDPAU with VLC in Ubuntu 22.10 (kinetic). The decoder fails to initialize and VLC displays a black screen (plus audio). This does not happen with the same NVIDIA driver in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy). My current workaround is to uninstall VDPAU. This is discussed here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2479684

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, browser was sluggish and even moving mouse would make youtube drop frames, thus why I was looking into enabling hardware acceleration.

Running just `vainfo` would fail but:

```
$ vainfo --display drm --device /dev/dri/renderD128
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Skylake - 2.1.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointStats
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointStats
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointFEI
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointStats
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
```

I realized the OS is only looking into first GPU for `vainfo` and HWA, and after changing **prime** GPU using:

```
$ sudo nvidia-settings
$ # or alternatively
$ sudo prime-select intel
```

And resetting, both started to work:

```
$ vainfo --display drm --device /dev/dri/renderD129
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 20.0.8 for NV118
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
```

My CPU is 20°C cooler and I can scroll smoothly and watch videos without frames dropping.