# vainfo fail in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: intel-graphics, intel, hardware-acceleration

I am using i5-8500 with intel UHD-630 graphics.
Already I installed next packages.
sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver vainfo

But vainfo prints this message.

```
sky@sky:~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Have you any idea?
Any quick suggestions will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vainfo returns "libva error: /usr/lib/x86\_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965\_drv\_video.so init failed" in dual gpu system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093954/vainfo-returns-libva-error-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-dri-i965-drv-video-so-ini)